# How to indentity a folder where a file has changed after merged into Git master branch?

Tags: bash, git, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I'm working on creating a repository for storing all Dockerfiles and using GitLab CI for building container images.
For example, we have the next folder structure in the master branch:

```
.
├── nginx
│   └── Dockerfile
└── postgres
    └── Dockerfile
```

and I create new feature branch from master and add new folder mysql with Dockerfile and merged feature branch into master:

```
.
├── mysql
│   └── Dockerfile
├── nginx
│   └── Dockerfile
└── postgres
    └── Dockerfile
```

So, how after merge to detect a new folder or changes of the existing folder ( if we changed Dockerfile in nginx and postgres folders)??

Because I want to have a **$DIR** variable in my pipeline that will point on new/changed Dockerfile in the folder, something like:

```
build_image:
  stage: build
  script:
  - docker build --no-cache -t gcr.io/my-project/$image.$CI_PIPELINE_IID $DIR
```

If we changed Dockerfile in *nginx* folder, **$DIR** will equal "./nginx/Dockerfile" or another example where we added a new folder *mysq*l than **$DIR** will equal "./mysql/Dockerfile".

Comment: Git doesn't store *folders* in the first place: Git stores *files*, whose names happen to look like they're made out of folder-and-file names, but they are just *file* names: `mysql/Dockerfile`, `nginx/Dockerfile`, and so on. These files are stored inside *commits* and each commit is a *full snapshot of every file* (that Git knew about at the time you, or whoever, made the commit). To find *changes* in specific files, you tell Git to `diff` two *commits*.

Comment: The output of `git diff` or (for scripts) `git diff-tree` is selectable; in your case, you'd want to list the *names of differing files* so you might use `git diff-tree -r --name-only <hash1> <hash2>` to compare the two commits with the given hash IDs. From there, you can do whatever you like with the resulting file names. Note that any given pair of commits' comparisons could indicate changes in no, or two or all three, Docker files. You will need to decide what to do about that.

Comment: If you want to know if some file is new, or deleted, consider using `--name-status` rather than `--name-only`. A status letter `A` means the file is "new" in the second commit: it's absent from the first snapshot, but present in the second. A status letter `D` means that the file is "deleted" in the second commit: present in the first, gone in the second.